# How to shorten the code where are multiple if statements?

Tags: php

I was thinking about this some time. I'm using a lot if statements, and sometimes I have a lot of them. I know I can use `switch` to shorten a bit the code. Is there another way to shorten them?

Let's say we have this example:

```php
$all_conditions = '';

        if($post_status != ""){
            $conditions[] = "posts.post_status = '".$post_status."'";
        }
        if($post_type != ""){
            $conditions[] = "posts.post_type = '".$post_type."'";
        }
        if($meta_key != ""){
            $conditions[] = "postmeta.meta_key = '".$meta_key."'";
        }
        if($meta_value != ""){
            $conditions[] = "postmeta.meta_value = '".$meta_value."'";
        }
        if($date_begin != "" && $date_end != ""){
            $conditions[] = "( posts.post_date BETWEEN '".$date_begin."' AND '".$date_end."' )";
        }
        if(count($conditions)>0){
            $all_conditions = implode(" AND ",$conditions);
        }
        if($all_conditions != ""){
            $all_conditions = "WHERE ".$all_conditions;
        }
```

What should I do to not repeat all those if's?

Comment: since in every condition parameter  is different you can not shorten this code, may be you can make array and check with loop but it will only shorten loc and add more processing which isnt a good idea, AFIAT

Comment: also you need to maintain the readability of the code so yea you are right use switch or this code is just fine.

Comment: What's wrong with this code that it needs to be "shortened"?  It looks pretty clear and straightforward to me.  You can easily abstract it into a well-named method so that the overall operation being performed can focus on its own readability and not be cluttered with this.  But this logic itself is pretty clear.

Comment: I thought there might be a way that I didn't encountered yet. Maybe it is, maybe it isn't. @David, can you exemplify what you said please.

Comment: @David most of newbie thinks less loc === good code

Comment: @NullPoiиteя: Well that's just silly.  Whoever is teaching them that really needs to stop :)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, I don't think that. I think less loc === good readability, faster way to implement. Those are two of the many reason I could think about right now.

Comment: Anonymous and exactly this is whats wrong. Less code really doesnt mean to be more readable

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, I think that Sanjay Kumar N S's answer contradicts you.

Comment: @Anonymous no not at all, so you have increased no of line from 7 to 9 and added loop and array, which will cause more processing. I dont buy his logic, anyway's Whatever float the boat, i am done here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$all_conditions = '';
$checkArr = array('post_status' =>  'posts.post_status',
                  'post_type'   =>  'posts.post_type',
                  'meta_key'    =>  'postmeta.meta_key',
                  'meta_value'  =>  'postmeta.meta_value');
foreach ($checkArr AS $key => $val) {
    if (${$key} != '') {
        $conditions[] = "$val = '${$key}'";
    }
}
if($date_begin != "" && $date_end != ""){
    $conditions[] = "( posts.post_date BETWEEN '".$date_begin."' AND '".$date_end."' )";
}
if(count($conditions)>0){
    $all_conditions = "WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$conditions);
}  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best educated guess is the you retrieve the $post_status via a `$post_status = $_POST['status']` kinda way, in that case you can shorten it like this (one of more ways to do it):

```
$all_conditions = '';    
$mandatoryFields = array( 'status', 'type', 'key', 'value' );

foreach ( $mandatoryFields as $mandatoryField ) {
    if ( $_POST[$mandatoryField] != '' ) {
        $conditions[] = 'posts.`post_' . $mandatoryField  . '` = "'.$_POST[$mandatoryField].'"';
    }
}
```

Then go and add begin and end dates and take your code from there.

Answer (score 0):

### No-tech answer

I use checks like that sometimes too, and I do not think that it should be packed with a foreach statements, because that reduces code legibility and mainainablility. However, it does make sense if you have more than 10 similar conditions. But you can make it imho much more readable by not putting the conditional inside a block, and maybe adding some structure && comments:

```
// check fields
if($post_status != "") $conditions[] = "posts.post_status = '".$post_status."'";
if($post_type != "") $conditions[] = "posts.post_type = '".$post_type."'";
if($meta_key != "") $conditions[] = "postmeta.meta_key = '".$meta_key."'";
if($meta_value != "") $conditions[] = "postmeta.meta_value = '".$meta_value."'";

// check dates
if($date_begin != "" && $date_end != "") $conditions[] = "( posts.post_date BETWEEN '".$date_begin."' AND '".$date_end."' )";

// any conditions present?
if(count($conditions)>0) {
    $all_conditions = implode(" AND ",$conditions);
    $all_conditions = "WHERE ".$all_conditions;
}
else $all_conditions = '';
```

I have also put the string concatenation inside the `count($conditions)>0`, so you need not check twice.